# Set of real values of $k$ such that $4\cdot 2^{2x}-4k\cdot 2^x+5-4k\geq 0$ has a real solution

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality, exponential-function, quadratics

> Complete set of real values of $k$ for which
>
> $4\cdot 2^{2x}-4k\cdot 2^x+5-4k\geq 0$ has at least
>
> one real solution .

Try: From $$4k(2^x+1)\leq 4\cdot 2^{2x}+5$$

$$4k\leq \frac{4\cdot 2^{2x}+5}{2^x+1}$$

put $2^{x}=t>1$ for all $x \in R$

$$4k\leq \frac{4t^2+5}{t+1}=4(t-1)+\frac{9}{t+1}$$

let $\displaystyle f(t) = 4(t-1)+\frac{9}{t+1}$ and $\displaystyle f'(t)=4-\frac{9}{(t+1)^2}>0$ for $t>1$

so function $f(t)$ is strictly increasing function

$$4k<\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{4t^2+5}{t+1}<\infty\Rightarrow k<\infty$$

could some help me where i am missing

Comment: the collection of words in yellow is not a sentence, as no verb appears in it. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: For $x=-1$, we have $2^x = \frac{1}{2} < 1$, so your statement that $t > 1$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler argument than my original answer: for any given $k \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} 4 \cdot 2^{2x} - 4k \cdot 2^x = \lim_{t \to \infty} 4t^2 - 4kt = \infty$, so the quantity $4 \cdot 2^{2x} - 4k \cdot 2^x$ can be made arbitrarily large by taking $x$ sufficiently large and positive. In particular, it can be made greater than or equal to $4k-5$, whence there is always a real solution to the desired inequality, and so any $k \in \mathbb{R}$ works.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as a quadratic in $t=2^x$ right from the start. So, you're looking at the quadratic $4t^2 + 4kt + 5-4k$. Determine the range of $t \in \mathbb{R}$ in terms of $k$ for which this quadratic is non-negative, and then determine the values of $x$ to which these values of $t$ correspond (if there are any).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right! You got that all real value of $k$ is valid and it gives the answer: $\mathbb R$.

Indeed, you got:
$$k\leq\frac{4\cdot2^{2x}+5}{4(2^x+1)},$$ which gives that for all real $k$ there is real $x$, for which this inequality is true.

You proved it!

Comment: Their answer is correct but their reasoning is incorrect regarding the range of $t$ which they must consider.

Comment: @Sam Streeter  I don't agree with you! I added something in my post for you.

Comment: No, really, look at their argument. They say $2^x > 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and that is not true. Yes, it does not affect the conclusion or really the argument, but it is still an incorrect statement made in their proof.

Comment: @Sam Streeter It does not change something! The solution of the starting problem is right! Try to think about this. Read please again my post.

Comment: They have literally stated something which is false in their proof, Michael. How can you say that this is right? They even go on to say that $f\left(t\right)$ is a strictly increasing function, and that is not true. Once you realise that $t$ can be made arbitrarily small, you see that the derivative of this function has negative values for $t \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$. Yes, it only really matters what happens for large values of $t$, so this doesn't affect the important bit of the argument, but it's still not good mathematics, and this is supposed to be a place for people to learn.

Comment: Note that I'm not talking about your solution here. I'm talking about the fact that you said that they proved it in their original post, because their proof is not a good proof. It contains a mistake.

Comment: @Sam Streeter  He wrote that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{4t^2+5}{t+1}=+\infty$. It's enough. By the way, your first post does not get something and your second post follows from mine.

Comment: Yes, that part is correct, and that is enough, but that doesn't change the fact that other parts are incorrect. If they got rid of the statement $2^x > 1$ and the bit about $f\left(t\right)$ being a strictly increasing function, I agree that it's then a correct proof. Is a correct proof still correct if I throw in the phrase $\pi = e$ at the end? I appreciate that this discussion of the subtleties of good mathematics is pretty tedious, but this is a mathematical community and we should be encouraging good mathematics.

Comment: My second post does not follow from yours. You neglect to prove that the function on the right can be made arbitrarily large, however obvious that may be.

Comment: @Sam Streeter It's not my down voting.

Comment: No worries Michael. It's a little disheartening to see somebody down-voting that answer, even though it's a pretty tricky way of solving the problem, but I guess it's fair enough. I hope it's clear that I'm just trying to encourage the best possible mathematical practice here, and I understand that a lot of people don't care about an irrelevant mistake in a proof as long as the "heart" of the argument is right.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are a few errors in your try, what you are trying to do looks good to me.

As Sam Streeter pointed out in the comments, $2^x=t\gt 1$ is incorrect. It should be $2^x=t\gt 0$.

Since
$$f'(t)=\frac{(2t-1)(2t+5)}{(t+1)^2}$$
we see that $f(t)$ is decreasing for $0\lt t\lt\frac 12$ and is increasing for $t\gt \frac 12$ with $f(\frac 12)=4$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$. (All we need to know is $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$.)

(For every positive real $t$, there is $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $2^x=t$, so we want to find all $k$ such that there exists at least one *positive* real number $t$ satisfying $4k\le f(t)$, so...)

It follows that the answer is $\mathbb R$.